# How does Qt store the Qtoggleviewaction state?

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

When I tried to use a Qtoggleaction of a QTreeView, I was surprised that the checked state of the action in the menu tool is maintained even after I reopen my application. Does it internally use QSettings somewhere to store them ? Is it possible to see this stored configuration ?

Sample Code:

---

```
QAction* myToggleAction = myDockWidget->toggleViewAction();
myToggleAction->setEnabled(true);
myToggleAction->setOn(false);
```

---

Now I go to my menu and add this action. I launch the GUI and set it checked. I close and reopen the application, I can see it still checked !! wow

How does Qt do it ? Thanks in advance.